# Code Inspection - Find files that have no @charset defined

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, phpstorm, webstorm

I want to use the [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2018.1/structural-search-and-replace-dialogs.html?utm_campaign=PS&utm_content=2018.1&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product) option under Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> General -> Structural Search Inspection to find .scss/.sass files that are lacking the string `@charset "utf-8";`.

So far, I've added an "Option" called "charset" and the search template contains the string `@charset "utf-8";`. How do I proceed from here? When clicking on "Edit Variables" I only see this, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

[image: Edit Variables]

Comment: Is Edit > Find > Find in Path not an option? Why do you need to use structural search?

Comment: I thought this was an option of the code inspection. I basically want an inspection rule that checks for the presence of the string and displays an error if none is present

Comment: Structural search is more about searching for some code structures rather than particular strings: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace.html . It won't be able to tell you that the string is not there. If you need to find if a particular string is present in the set of files or not, I'd recommend to use Find in Path along with file mask and/or scope and then operate with results in Find window (button in the bottom right corner of Find in Path dialog) - you'll be able to export the results and check which files are not there.

Comment: @VladLuchansky is there another way to get phpstorm to use code inspection for that? I'd like to utilize auto fix from  the inspection results tool window since I have a fairly large codebase

Comment: Apart from a separate inspection or a custom plugin that would introduce this inspection - no. Feel free to submit a feature request for that at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB#newissue=yes

Comment: @VladLuchansky what do you mean by "separate inspection"? Can you link me to that?

Comment: By separate inspection I meant the inspection that would be introduced by WEB team - that's what feature request is for.

Comment: @VladLuchansky did that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34014